# Using an URL image with an UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uiimage, afnetworking

I am attempting to set an URL image to an UIButton in swift 4. I am using AFNetworking to load my images from the urls. I am seeing what is the best route to take in order to set the image to the button.

Using `.setImage()` or `setImageWith()` does not work with urls and uibuttons.

This is the URL being used:

`let imageUrl = URL(string: baseUrl + profile)`

Comment: Download the button from the URL, save it locally if required, apply it to the button

Comment: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/UIKit%2BAFNetworking/UIButton%2BAFNetworking.h There should be all the methods you want there without the needs of using a different library.

Comment: Please see my answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/56616298/3904109

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) it has a category/extension for the `UIButton` too

```
btn.sd_setImage(with:URL(string: "Your_url"), forState:.normal)
```

Comment: I am trying this cell.bProfileImage.sd_setImage(with:URL(string: individualChatsListArray[indexPath.row].profile_image), forState:.normal) but getting error Value of optional type 'UIButton?' must be unwrapped to refer to member 'sd_setImage' of wrapped base type 'UIButton'

Comment: replace `cell.bProfileImage.` with `cell.bProfileImage!.`

Comment: But, If I am using kingfisher library?

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting because the current answer suggests another library (`SDWebImage`) while `AFNetworking` already provides an extension for `UIButton` with [`UIButton + AFNetworking.h`](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/UIKit%2BAFNetworking/UIButton%2BAFNetworking.h) (and `.m`).

The declaration are in Objective-C, but you should be able to use the Swift equivalent one in your code:

```
- (void)setImageForState:(UIControlState)state
                 withURL:(NSURL *)url;
- (void)setImageForState:(UIControlState)state
                 withURL:(NSURL *)url
        placeholderImage:(nullable UIImage *)placeholderImage;
- (void)setImageForState:(UIControlState)state
          withURLRequest:(NSURLRequest *)urlRequest
        placeholderImage:(nullable UIImage *)placeholderImage
                 success:(nullable void (^)(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse * _Nullable response, UIImage *image))success
                 failure:(nullable void (^)(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError *error))failure;
```

There is also the same versions for the backgroundImage.